# reactjs conditional rendering with appstate bugging

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

when i dot conditional rendering in my reactjs project it only sometimes does what i want it to and its driving me insane.
i am very new to react + typescript and working with axios, and this is not how i will render its just to test. i will use protected routes instead of conditionally returning everything

```
export interface AppState {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  user: number | null;
  loading: boolean;
}

const initState: AppState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  user: null,
  loading: false,
}



function App() {

  const [appState, setAppState] = useState<AppState>(initState);

  const isLoggedIn = appState.isLoggedIn;

  if(isLoggedIn){
  return(
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet> 
        <IonContent>
          <IonTabs>
            <IonRouterOutlet>
                <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/facilities" user={appState.isLoggedIn} component={Facilities}> 
                </ProtectedRoute>
                <Route exact path="/login">
                  <Login appState={appState} setAppState={setAppState}/>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to="/facilities"></Redirect>
                </Route>
            </IonRouterOutlet>
            
            <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
              <IonTabButton tab="Facilities" href="/facilities">
                <IonLabel>Facilities</IonLabel>
              </IonTabButton>
              <IonTabButton>
                <IonLabel>Test2</IonLabel>
              </IonTabButton>
            </IonTabBar>
          </IonTabs>
        </IonContent>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
  );
} else {
return(
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <IonContent>
            <IonRouterOutlet>
                <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} /> 
                <Route exact path="/login">
                  <Login appState={appState} setAppState={setAppState}/>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to="/login"></Redirect>
                </Route>
            </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonContent>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
  );
}
};

export default App;
```

Comment: "bugging" and "does what I want" aren't very specific. What behavior are you expecting, and what other behavior are you seeing instead?

Comment: @samuei so it randomly shows for example the isLoggedIn return but then on refresh doesnt anymore, and does this all the time. is it smth with my macbook? or is it the conditional not workin is the question